# mysql server doesn't recognize changes in my.cnf

Tags: mysql, centos

I have installed mysql server and mysql client with bundle in Centos 7. mysql server's port is displayed as 0. I want to give specific port to it. For this purpose, I have changed **/etc/my.cnf** with below;

```
port=4545
```

After changes, I've restarted the service. But it's start with skip-networking as ON. I have also tried to change skip-networking to OFF but didn't accomplish.

I have also tried mysql_secure_installation after changes but got below error :

> Failed! Error: The MySQL server is running with the
> --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

How can i solve this?
Thanks for answering

Comment: Investigate [Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html). Find those files which are really loaded during service starting, then edit correct file and restart service.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question with below;

```
systemctl stop mysqld
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-networking=OFF"
```

After this I have started service again.

```
systemctl start mysqld
```